# Using Line Pointer Controls with Packed Decimals SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use line pointer controls in my SAS program which utilizes many INPUT statements based on the value of certain variables. Many of my fields contain packed decimals and I think this is causing issues with the line-pointer controls, it seems that the program doesn't determine the packed decimal before it unpacks and has moved the column pointer incorrectly.

I have no way of knowing how many of my 'segments' to read, I just know the maximum number that is possible, so I will be needing to check values through the program before reading the data and use relative pointer controls based on that 'segment'. I'll be looping and using line-pointer controls (INPUT +N) to accomplish this.

My old program worked correctly when I ***knew*** the exact columns I needed to read in, so I simply used an input statement with.

Here's a sample of the old program, I'm only including the top portion because it will illustrate what I had:

```
....some rsubmitting and options statements....
  %DO i=0 %TO 2;

filename MyFN "MyFile(-&i.)" disp=shr;

DATA ReadInTemp;
INFILE MyFN MISSOVER PAD;
INPUT
 @1     Pro_Ind             $1. @;
    IF Pro_Ind ="H" or Pro_Ind ="T" THEN DELETE;
    IF Pro_Ind ="1" THEN DO; 
        INPUT 
            @2  Time_Stamp              ? PD8.
            @10 MyVar2                      ? $1.
            @11 MyVar3                  ? $20.
            @31 MyVar4                      ? $2.
```

Here's the program I'm trying with Line Controls:

```
....some rsubmitting and options statements....
    %DO i=0 %TO 2;

filename MyFN "MyFile(-&i.)" disp=shr;

DATA ReadInTemp;
INFILE MyFN missover pad;
INPUT
 @1     Pro_Ind             $1. @;
    IF Pro_Ind ="H" or Pro_Ind ="T" THEN DELETE;
    IF Pro_Ind ="1" THEN DO;
        INPUT 
            @2  Time_Stamp          ? PD8. +7
                MyVar1              ? $1.  +1
                MyVar2              ? $20. +19
                MyVar3              ? $2.  +1
```

Please keep in mind this is only the sample of where A) the program used to work and B) where it is not working now. I understand that there is no END and %END statements, etc, but I believe my issue is after I am reading this TimeStamp variable which contains the Packed Decimal.

Comment: What is your file format? Add some sample input data?

Comment: I think the issue is that the informat will advance the column pointer by the informat width, and then you are explicitly advanced more.  To be certain the informat takes up the correct number of characters try using $CHARn. instead of $n.

Comment: @Richard wow, awesome! This worked! I hadn’t even thought about char informer passing blanks because of how often I use absolute column input or delimited files. Do you want to write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in your *program with line controls* is that the informat will advance the column pointer by the informat width, and then you are explicitly advancing more.

To be certain the informat reads the data as-is (retain leading spaces @Tom) use `$CHARw.` instead of `$w.` and **remove the extraneous `+n`**

```
INPUT 
     @2  Time_Stamp          ? PD8.
         MyVar1              ? $CHAR1.
         MyVar2              ? $CHAR20.
         MyVar3              ? $CHAR2.
...
```

Comment: Use of `$CHARx.` instead of `$x.` will not change how the column pointer moves.  It will only will impact how the leading spaces are handled. With `$CHAR` the leading spaces are preserved. With `$` the value will be left aligned in the variable.